# Foley: a rolling rock

Tags: foley

I've got a scene which a huge rock is rolling down a mountain.how can I make this sound?  Is there a material I can use to make the sound?

Answer (score 1):

In Raiders of the Lost Ark, it sounds like a bunch of twigs and sticks snapping and then like crumbling paper with the high end taken out, with a little bit of cinder blocks being dragged on some concrete added in. It [actually](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raiders_of_the_Lost_Ark) is the sound of a car rolling down a gravel driveway in neutral.

Answer (score 1):

Car rolling downhill on gravel without engine running – record the wheel friction.
Ben Burtt´s Style

Answer (score 0):

Also roll a heavy ball, say a bowling ball along a hard floor. use that bass sound that subtle low tone to add body to the rock. For impacts drop a bag of dirt or ball into a pillow to get the low freq's. If it hits a tree record the leaf sound of you hitting a branch with your hand. Try clicking a few fist sized rocks together for impacts and clicks.